# Is it possible to achieve desired permutation of values for vertices with adjacent swaps?

Tags: c++, math, graph

Consider an arbitrary **connected** (acyclic/cyclic) **undirected** **graph** with **N** Vertices, with vertex numbered from **1** to **N**. Each vertex has some value assigned to it. Let the values be denoted by **A1, A2, A3, ... AN**, where **A[i]** denotes value of **ith** vertex. Let **P** be a permutation of **A**. Each operation, we can swap values of two **adjacent** vertices. Is it possible to achieve **A = P**, i.e. after all swapping operation **A[i] = P[i]** for all **1 <= i <= N**. In other words, each vertex **i** should have value **P[i]** after the operations.
P.S - I was confused about where to ask this - stack overflow or math.stack exchange. Apologies in advance.

Edit 1: I think the answer should be Yes. But I am only saying this on basis of case analysis of different types of graphs of 5 vertices. I tried to modify the permutation to Q where Q1 < Q2 < .. This changes a problem a bit that now final state should be A1 < A2 < A3... AN. So it can be said can the graph be sorted? Please correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is possible. Since we've got a connected graph, we can remove edges until you've got a tree. Removing an edge simply means we won't use it to do adjacent swaps in this case. "Removing a node" simply means we'll never swap the value of the node.

Now we can use the following algorithm to produce the permutation:

1. Choose a leaf and determine the position of the value intended to be located there after the permutation. Repeatedly swap the value with the next one on the path to the leaf until the value reaches the leaf.
2. Remove the leaf from the tree; the resulting graph still is a tree
3. Continue with 1., if there are any nodes left.

In each iteration we reduce the size of the graph by 1 by doing a number of swaps that can be bounded from above by the number of nodes, so with a finite number of swaps we're able to produce the premutation. The algorithm may not yield a solution using the optimum number of swaps, but it shows that it can be done.